# Add more (sets of) fields to form by jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

It is easy to add more fields to a html form by jQuery. Then, we can serialize the fields, if the have the same `name` but what if we have a set of fields? For example

```
<input type="text" name="movie1_name" />
<input type="text" name="movie1_director" />
<input type="text" name="movie1_year" />
```

Now I want to add a new set of fields by jQuery as

```
<input type="text" name="movie2_name" />
<input type="text" name="movie2_director" />
<input type="text" name="movie2_year" />
```

and so forth. I process the form with PHP to insert movies into mysql database with three columns of (name, director, year). In the above-mentioned example, it is hard to serialize the fields to create appropriate $_POST arrays. How should I serialize jquery-added sets of movies?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I added more description to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on useful discussion with `Cheery`, I came to conclusion that the best and safest way is to use

```
<input type="text" name="movie_name[i]" />
<input type="text" name="movie_director[i]" />
<input type="text" name="movie_year[i]" />
```

where we define each `i` with jQuery to serialize the fields SAFELY. This way, we can be sure that serialized arrays are parallel and well matched, without misplacing.

Comment: I don't understand how the fields could be misplaced in anyway as you mention? If you add the new field accordingly, it should follow that the second name would be added as the second director and year (and so on).

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="text" name="movie_name[]" />
<input type="text" name="movie_director[]" />
<input type="text" name="movie_year[]" />

<input type="text" name="movie_name[]" />
<input type="text" name="movie_director[]" />
<input type="text" name="movie_year[]" />
```

Nothing else. On the server you will get (in case of POST) array in $_POST['movie_name'], $_POST['movie_director'] and $_POST['movie_year'];. Elements with the same index are from the same set of inputs.

What kind of problem with serialization do you have?

```
<form>   
<input type="text" name="movie_name[]" />
<input type="text" name="movie_director[]" />
<input type="text" name="movie_year[]" />
<hr />
<input type="text" name="movie_name[]" />
<input type="text" name="movie_director[]" />
<input type="text" name="movie_year[]" />
 <br />
<input type='button' id='serialize' value='Click me' />
</form>
```

and js code:

```
$('#serialize').click(function(){
    alert($('form').serialize()); 
});
```

when you want to submit the data just write

```
 $.post('script.php', $('form').serialize(), function() {alert('Saved');});
```

ps: if you are afraid to lose something, just compare count($_POST['movie_name']), count($_POST['movie_director']) and count($_POST['movie_year']).

or you can add indexes

```
   <input type="text" name="movie_name[0]" />
   <input type="text" name="movie_director[0]" />
   <input type="text" name="movie_year[0]" />

   <input type="text" name="movie_name[1]" />
   <input type="text" name="movie_director[1]" />
   <input type="text" name="movie_year[1]" />
```

Comment: First I was thinking of this way; but imagine due to a fault one single field (e.g. movie_director2) is not submitted. Then fields will be misplaced in rows. I know it is improbable; but it can lead to a chaos in the database with wrong data (scary).

Comment: @Ali How it could be not submitted? Count each array and check that you have same number of elements. Add indexes, if you are afraid of something.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="movie1_name" />
<input type="text" name="movie1_director" />
<input type="text" name="movie1_year" />
// OTHER:
<input type="text" name="movie2_name" />
<input type="text" name="movie2_director" />
<input type="text" name="movie2_year" />
```

And do this to all... In Jquery, you create a function that create field as needed... I'm not the best in JQuery so I can't help you for this but the way I told you worked fine for me with PHP...

Comment: then how to read it with PHP? $_POST['movie2_name'], but how many movies we have? Imagine we have until $_POST['movie15_name'], we should examine one by one.

Comment: I think there's a way to count number of `$_POST['movieXX_name']` in PHP and create a `foreach()`... Browser Google or ask a question... I'm not using this 'cause the `foreach()` function, I hate it.